# How to replace only 1 element in a DataFrame (Python-Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

:D
I have a dataframe like that, which each 5 mins categorical information comes to be appened in it.
The index is the same date (`ìndex_date`) and the categorical data is the column `Fruits`. The column `Number` counts how much of each fruit it recieves each 5 minutes, always increasing their valor and the column `Diff_number` is the diference with the last categorical data incoming.
The col `Diff_number` is made with:

`df['Diff_number'] = df.groupby(['Fruit'])['Number'].diff().fillna(0)`

| **index_date** | Fruits | Number | Diff_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **16:10:16.000** | Apple | 1 | 0 |
| **16:10:16.000** | Grapes | 3 | 0 |
| **16:10:16.000** | Orange | 4 | 0 |
| **16:15:16.000** | Apple | 5 | 4 |
| **16:15:16.000** | Grapes | 8 | 5 |
| **16:15:16.000** | Orange | 10 | 6 |
| **16:20:16.000** | Apple | 10 | 5 |
| **16:20:16.000** | Grapes | 8 | 0 |
| **16:20:16.000** | Orange | 1 | -9 |

For example. At `16:10:16.000` it gets 1 apple with 0 difference and 5 mins after it gets in total 5 apples with 4 of difference.
All is good here but my question is:

Is there any way to eliminate that -9 and always takes the number in the column `Number`?

What I expect is this:

| **index_date** | Fruits | Number | Diff_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **16:10:16.000** | Apple | 1 | 0 |
| **16:10:16.000** | Grapes | 3 | 0 |
| **16:10:16.000** | Orange | 4 | 0 |
| **16:15:16.000** | Apple | 5 | 4 |
| **16:15:16.000** | Grapes | 8 | 5 |
| **16:15:16.000** | Orange | 10 | 6 |
| **16:20:16.000** | Apple | 10 | 5 |
| **16:20:16.000** | Grapes | 8 | 0 |
| **16:20:16.000** | Orange | 1 | 1 |

When the col `Number` for some reason stops to count incrementally, `Diff_number` col takes the value of `Number` only in that row.

**Actualization**
I tried to do that:

```
if df.iloc[index]['Diff_number'] < 0:
   df.iloc[index]["Diff_numver"] = df.iloc[index]["Number"]
```

But it doesn't work :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
if df.iloc[row]['Diff_number'] < 0:
   df.at[row, 'Diff_number'] = df.iloc[row]['Number']
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. 
It keeps containing the original values.

Comment: I tried again and it works! :D
Before try it I must to reset index. Thank you so much, Sir!